# Не удается развернуть проект на win10 ошибка внутренней переменной

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows, typescript

[image: На скрине мой json, такой же как на маке]
Пытался развернуть готовый проект на винде, к слову на  macOs все заводится без ошибки, пробовал добавлять node, но вылетает ошибка о не нахождении модуля, я не понимаю в чем проблема винды и что нужно с этим делать, я уже установливал nodeJS как глобальную переменную

Comment: Вам нужно `REACT_APP...` как переменную окружения установить?

Comment: Я не знаю что он от меня хочет, возможно да

Comment: Если верить этому [ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198310/how-to-set-node-env-to-production-development-in-os-x), то вам надо просто написать `SET` перед `REACT_APP...`

Comment: У меня тоже были проблемы с ОС. Дома Мас. на работе Винда, сервер на Убунту. Советую использовать [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env), подойдет и для винда и для apple, и для линукс [Пример](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQFO3.png)